# Where are registered servers stored?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SMS 2008 & I'm looking for where the registered servers are stored on my local machine.  I have searched the registry with no luck.

Comment: Although it's been answered, this belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are kept as an XML document here:

> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml

On Windows XP this resolves to:

> C:\Documents and Settings\*username*\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml

**Note**: As of Windows Vista there is no **Application Data** folder, and the path resolves differently.

Comment: you should mention that the studio version \100\ might change according other versions (not asked, i know)

Comment: This answers applies only to the SSMS that was included in SQL Server (up to 2014). See the other answer for SSMS v17 and v18.

Answer (score 15):

For Windows 10 and SSMS version V17 the document can be found using this path in windows explorer

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio
```

Or this powershell command

```
dir "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\RegSrvr.xml"

    Example
    Directory: C:\Users\george\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       19/02/2019   4:04 PM          60998 RegSrvr.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

In windows 8 and 7 here is the correct path.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml
```

Comment: Nope, the accepted answer is missing the roaming folder and this answer specifies that ;)

Comment: No, the accepted answer correctly says %APPDATA% which IS the correct macro for the roaming folder. Your answer incorrectly assumes that your Roaming folder is in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\, which it won't necessarily be.