# Where are SQL Server 2012 Management Studio connections stored?

Tags: sql-server, connection

All of my saved connections (Server name & Authentication) in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio disappeared yesterday morning.

It would be easier to restore the data from back-up and not have to re-create each entry.

Where is the server name & authentication data stored?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the remembered login and password list in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349668/removing-the-remembered-login-and-password-list-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064289/where-are-registered-servers-stored. Path will include "110" for SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Following Dan's "possible duplicate" response, I navigated to C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Shell\RegServer.xml, which has the xml to edit.

Ahmed's "possible duplicate" response directed me to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin but that file was identifies as a VLS media file and not editable Notepad++.

Note the AppData folder was invisible but could be navigated to directly using the path.

Thanks